# Reading Excel file using C# - External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read Excel *.xlsx file. 
Getting error "External table is not in the expected format"
I had two files one is getting read but other one is not able to read. for second file the exception is thrown for

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [ID] FROM [mySheet$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "IDs_Create");
```

two files having same data
Please help in what is the possible reason for this exception
I tried to check Column name [ID] both are same. 
File Extentions are also same.

Comment: How was the file which is causing the error created? I have discovered that Excel .XLSX-format files created with the Open XML SDK are sometimes not readable by the OleDb libraries.

Comment: Also, if you are going to be running this code on a server, you shouldn't use OLEDB because those libraries aren't designed to run on a sever. The Office Interops are not as well.

Comment: @krillgar - Could you elaborate on that? OleDb libraries are fundamental to how many of the linked servers and other external sources connect to SQL Server et al, so I'm not clear how "OleDB" "isn't designed to run on a server."

Comment: Try using this format for your connection string. 

@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";

Comment: @DavidW Perhaps I'm wrong then about OLEDB. I know for a fact that Office isn't. I remember having issues trying to get OLEDB to work as well. Using a third party tool to work with Excel is a far better and easier solution.

Comment: @krillgar Now I will absolutely agree that Office apps per se are not supposed to be directly manipulated on a server-side app. That makes sense...just wanted to make sure there wasn't something going on re OleDB :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the file you're attempting to use, have any formulas (functions) in the "ID" column?

Comment: No formulas .. it is only showing green triangle symbol at the top left corner for each cell of this column

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-are-those-buttons-and-triangles-in-my-cells-203e34e6-ba90-4158-ae58-33397dda3ca9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmtriangles

Comment: These green triangles are indicative of error in the formula

Comment: Is there any way to read the data from such file .. without using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" ?